# Emmet How To Wrap Usig Multiple Tags

Tags: visual-studio-code, phpstorm, sublimetext3, atom-editor, emmet

I'm trying to wrap bunch of data with following tags.

For an example:

```
link1
link2
link3
link4
link5
```

I want each one of them to be wrapped with following tags.

```
<url>
<loc>link1</loc>
<lastmod>2020-01-16T22:59:45+00:00</lastmod>
<priority>0.80</priority>
</url>

<url>
<loc>link2</loc>
<lastmod>2020-01-16T22:59:45+00:00</lastmod>
<priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
....
```

I want to know if this is possible to do using Emmet code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably easier to just make a vscode snippet.  Are the times fixed or change to when the link is updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative is to use regular snippets.  This is for vscode:

```
"link snippet": {
  "prefix": "link",
  "body": [
    "<url>"
    "<loc>$TM_SELECTED_TEXT</loc>",

    "<lastmod>2020-01-16T22:59:45+00:00</lastmod>",  // if date is fixed ahead of time

       // use below if date is dynamic at creation time
     "<lastmod>${CURRENT_YEAR}-${CURRENT_MONTH}-${CURRENT_DATE}T${CURRENT_HOUR}:${CURRENT_MINUTE}:${CURRENT_SECOND}+00:00</lastmod>"

    "<priority>0.80</priority>",
    "</url>",
    ""
  ],
  "description": "Wrap link with url, etc."
},
```

Then, because you will need to chain 3 commands together to make this easy, use a macro extension like [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command).  Pu this into your settings.json:

```
  "multiCommand.commands": [

    {
      "command": "multiCommand.expandLink",
      "sequence": [
        "editor.action.insertCursorAtEndOfEachLineSelected",
        "cursorHomeSelect",
        {
          "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
          "args": {
            "name": "link snippet",
          }
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
```

That will trigger the snippet after it selects each of your lines separately.  To trigger the macro itself you need a keybinding (in keybindings.json):

```
{ 
  "key": "shift+alt+l",
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": { "command": "multiCommand.expandLink" },
},
```

A fair amount of setup, but then it is just the one keybinding to trigger it all.  Demo:

[image: wrap link demo]

Answer (score 3):

There are two things you should use from Emmet syntax:

- Implicit repeater: mark element with `*` (without number) to Emmet to repeat element as many as lines you’re wrapping. For example, `ul>li*`
- Output placeholder: tell Emmet where to put content you are wrapping with `$#`. You can use it in text (`li{Put here: $#}`) and/or in attributes (`li[title=$#]`).

So, in the end your wrapping abbreviation will look like this:

```
url*>loc{$#}+lastmod{2020-01-16T22:59:45+00:00}+priority{0.8}
```

Note that, for some reason, in VSCode you should use *Emmet: Wrap Individual Lines with Abbreviation* command to wrap multiple lines while in other editors the default *Wrap With Abbreviation* should work.

Read more about abbreviation syntax: https://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/

Answer (score 2):

In PHPStorm, I'd suggest defining a [live template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2019.3/using-live-templates.html) for that:

```
<url>
<loc>$SELECTION$</loc>
<lastmod>$date$</lastmod>
<priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
```

where `$date$` has `date("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")` used as *Expression*:

[image]

Now enable *column selection mode* (**Edit | Column Selection Mode**), select the lines you'd like to surround with tags, choose **Code > Surround With Live Template...**